# Simplifying a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series like this:

$$1 + \frac 1 {x^2} + \frac 1 {x^4} + \frac 1 {x^6} ....$$

Is this a known series? Can I simplify this to something?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a geometric series.

Comment: Your series is just a geometric series, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^{-2n} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (x^{-2})^n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $|x|\gt 1$ your series will converge.  You can put $y=x^2$ and it is a standard [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: You mean $|x| > 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  Right.  In the denominator